# Pokémon Go - Can I use my android account if I change to an Iphone

Tags: pokemon-go

Was thinking about changing phone to an Iphone because my android is too slow for the game. Was wondering if i could still use my goodle account for android on my Iphone?

Thanks

Comment: Depending on how old your phone is, chances are it's your phone hardware that is struggling, and not your operating system.

Answer (score 1):

Yes both google account and trainer accounts can be used on android and apple devices interchangeably. I've personally used the same account on 2 androids and an iPhone (mostly due to the major battery drain).

Comment: ***Note:** If the birthdate is set to say you are 13 or younger, Google accounts won't be an option.*